why there is a spike in reactive power when clearing the fault in a Fault ride through for PV plant?
I am performing the FRT for PV plant. I am not able to understand why there is a spike in reactive power when clearing the fault. In addition to this, can anyone please also guide why there is not a smooth transition when restoring the power. Your help will highly be appreciated.


Can you show the relevant parts of the SLD? Where is the fault and which breaker open and isolates the fault so that it can produce again? Any cables of considerable length, transformer? What do you mean be smooth transition? Can you include plots of the current and voltage too? That makes it easier to answer.
